# Get latitude/longitude on click from an image

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have an image on which there are five points. These five points have specific latitude/longitude.
I want a way that when a user click on any of these points I get corresponding latitude/longitude of that point. 
Since points are in Image and not in map form I was thinking to use Radio buttons on points and use switch cases to map values of latitude/longitude of each point to its radio button.
Is it a right way? Or is there any other way to accompalish this task.

Comment: I don't know if it's the "right way" but it accomplishes the task and doesn't seem any more complicated than other methods would be.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you?

```
figure, imshow(pic,[]); 
title('Select four points'); hold on; 
[x,y] = ginput;
```

If not I do not understand the question.